# how to change the url of web service from localhost to www(word wide web)

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010, web-services

i have very simple problem , but the solution are very vast and complex ..
i have one asp.net web service . it is when i run it , url is like this :

http://:56197/Salesforce/SforceService.asmx?wsdl

i want to change it to like this :

http://www.site.com/Salesforce/SforceService.asmx?wsdl

what is mean to say just want to make web service globally and consume web service on remote in cross platform(salesforce)that URL dont to include and pc name of ip name

following suggestion i have tried :

- create a wsdl file and export in wsdl format ... but it also include end point address in this format
  /Salesforce/SforceService.asmx"/>

again local computer problem , how to modify soap url to access globally

- create a proxy class using wsdl tool --> it generate .cs class , if this is right way then how to consume it on client side salesforce

i followed these links :
http://www.justskins.com/forums/dynamically-change-url-in-61352.html
(equivalent done in c#)

```
Dim rswb as new Testing.Service1()
rswb.URL = "http://Testing/Group/Service1.asmx"
```

But on service.cs class it doesnot show url proeprty

I am bit of confused  and stuck
Please provide me any relative link ..
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Did you do a web reference or a service reference? I'm thinking you added a service refrence.  You might want to change it to a web reference

When you add a reference there is an advanced button.  Make sure you select add web reference.

I do this all the time adding a testing  web service on my local development machine and switch it to the production one in code.

Dim myWS As New myWS.Update
'//create a new instance of the webservice object
  Dim tmpURL as string = "ipaddress/domain name of actual host here"
  myWS.Url = "http://" & tmpURL & ".asmx"